# Сформировать файл ”STUDENT”. вывести список студентов-хозрасчетников, имеющих задолжность

Tags: c++

Сформировать файл ”STUDENT”, содержащий сведения об успеваемости студентов некоторой группы: фамилия, форма обучения (госбюджетная и хозрасчетная), итоги экзаменационной сессии по четырем предметам. Используя созданный файл, вывести список студентов-хозрасчетников, имеющих задолжность хоть по одной дисциплине.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>;
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

struct Student {
    string surname;
    string fstudy;
    int mark1;
    int mark2;
    int mark3;
    int mark4;
};

void DataInput(vector<Student>& data, size_t n) {
    Student temp;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++) {

        cout << "Surname: ";
        cin >> temp.surname;

        cout << "Form of study (state budget/self-supporting): ";
        getline(cin, temp.fstudy);

        cin.ignore(32767, '\n');

        cout << "Mark1: ";
        cin >> temp.mark1;

        cout << "Mark2: ";
        cin >> temp.mark2;

        cout << "Mark3: ";
        cin >> temp.mark3;

        cout << "Mark4: ";
        cin >> temp.mark4;

        cin.ignore(32767, '\n');

        cout << endl;

        data.push_back(temp);
    }
}

void DataIf(vector<Student>& data, string& ss) {
    ofstream fout("STUDENT.txt");
    for (auto& it : data) {
        if (it.fstudy == ss) {
            fout << "Surname: " << it.surname<< endl;
            fout << "Form of study (state budget/self-supporting): " << it.fstudy << endl;
            fout << "Mark 1: " << it.mark1 << endl;
            fout << "Mark 2: " << it.mark2 << endl;
            fout << "Mark 3: " << it.mark3 << endl;
            fout << "Mark 4: " << it.mark4 << endl;

            fout << endl;
        }
    }
}

int main() {

    size_t n;
    cout << "Vvedite kolichestvo studentov: ";
    cin >> n;
    cin.ignore(32767, '\n');
    vector<Student> data;
    DataInput(data, n);

   
    string ss;
    ss = "self-supporting";
    DataIf(data, ss);
}
```

Вот мой код. Помогите доработать его...

Comment: К сожалению, я всё ещё новичок, котрый только недавно начал изучать азы. Однако, мне дали непосильную задачу. Помогите...

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;
class Student
{
private:
    string name, form;
    int m1, m2, m4, m3;
    static int c;
public:
    void setIn()
    {
        cin >> name >> form;
        cin >> m1 >> m2 >> m3 >> m4;
    }
    static int counter();
    void getIn(ofstream &v)
    {
        v << name << " " << form << " " << m1 << " " << m2 << " " << m3 << " " << m4;
    }
};
int Student::c = 0;
int Student:: counter()
{
    return c++;
}
bool check(string a)
{
    if (a.find('2')!=string::npos)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else return 0;
}
int main()
{
    int n = 2;
    Student* list = new Student[n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        cout<<list[i].counter()<<endl<<endl;
        list[i].setIn();
    }
    ofstream Q("abc.txt");
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        list[i].getIn(Q);
        if (i != n - 1)
        {
            Q << endl;
        }
    }
    Q.close(); ifstream Z("abc.txt"); ofstream X("def.txt"); string t;
    while (!Z.eof())
    {
        getline(Z, t);
        if (check(t))
        {
            X <<t<<endl;
        }
    }
    Z.close(); X.close(); return INT16_MIN;
}
```